# Turning Multiple Layers On and Off in Photoshop with export image Script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have 1 group in photoshop in which there are multiple images which are hide by default except the first one, I looking to turn show every image one by one except first one and then export as image with merged first layer

**Note** : Please see the screenshots [Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPhwV.png)

Can someone point me in the direction whether it is possible with script or any action?

I've never scripted in Photoshop but trying to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Whole post edited, yet this script covers usability of the original script (that worked only on a single layer group) and also extends itself onto all layer groups.**

Script takes the layers from each layer groups in the file and iterates through all of them except the first one in the given group turning them on and off for saving. First layer in each group is always visible for a given group iteration. Exports as PNG but you may adjust anything you need - export options, path, file name etc. Created for CS6 but should work with any version, just check it out.

Any more information you may need is in the reference manual. Just Google for *Photoshop CS6/CC Javascript Reference*.

The code's below, just copy-paste it using Notepad and save as **jsx** file. You may test it using ExtendScript Toolkit (it has been installed together with anything from Adobe, you just need to find it). If it works as intended, place the file within *Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\Scripts* folder, restart Photoshop and the script will be accessible through *File > Scripts* menu. You may also bind a keyboard shortcut to it if this action needs to be repeated over and over many times. Cheers!

```
#target Photoshop
if (documents.length == 0) {
    alert("nothing opened");
} else {
    // start

    //setup
    var file = app.activeDocument;
    var groupsAmount = file.layerSets.length; // get the layer groups

    // iterate through groups
    for (var k=0; k < groupsAmount; k++) {

        hideAllLayers();
        var images = file.layerSets[k].layers; // get the layers from the given group
        file.layerSets[k].visible = true;
        images[0].visible = true; // show the first layer in this group

        // begin "i" from 1 to start from the 2nd layer
        for (var i=1; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].visible = true;
            exportimage(images[i].name);
            images[i].visible = false;                
        }
    }


   // function used to export image (adjust as you want accoring to the manual)
    function exportimage(name){
        var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();

            options.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
            options.PNG8 = false;
            options.transparency = true;
            options.optimized = true;

        // adjust path & name
        file.exportDocument(File(file.path+"/"+name+".png"),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);
    }

    // function to hide all layers
    // simplified version of http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/downloads/Hide%20All%20Layers%202-1-0.jsx
    function hideAllLayers() {
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
        var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        desc.putReference(cTID('null'), ref);
        executeAction(sTID('selectAllLayers'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putEnumerated(cTID('Lyr '), cTID('Ordn'), cTID('Trgt'));
        var list = new ActionList();
        list.putReference(ref);
        var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
        desc.putList(cTID('null'), list);
        executeAction(cTID('Hd  '), desc, DialogModes.NO);

    }
    function cTID(s) {return app.charIDToTypeID(s);}
    function sTID(s) {return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);}

    //end
}
```

Comment: It is work perfect! as I want but could you help me if there are multiple folders in the same file and I want to apply same thing on individual folder?

Comment: @LuicePhillips apologies for the reply time but simply had no time. Here's the extended version - works all the same yet covers all the groups. Enjoy!

Comment: thanks for the reply and I had give try on updated script and it is working fantastic.. thanks again for your help